# Command button not working properly

Tags: ms-access

I have set up a command button on a form that is meant to create invoices for holders that have provided direct debit information. I have four tables, Holder, Product(related to Holder), Transaction(related to Product) and Invoice(related to holder). The button searches for all holders that have direct debit indicated, cycles through those holders and finds all transactions that have not been previously invoiced, sums the transactions then enters the amount into a new record on the Invoice table. It then should cycle through the transactions it used to make the invoice and add the newly created invoice id to the transaction. Here is the code I am using:

Private Sub btnDebitInvoices_Click()

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstHolder As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstTrans As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstSum As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstInvoice As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQLSum As String
Dim strSQLHolder As String

Set db = CurrentDb

'Select all unique holders that have provided direct debit information
strSQLHolder = "SELECT DISTINCT HolderID " _
    & "FROM tblHolder " _
    & "WHERE (tblHolder.DirectDebit = 40);"

Set rstHolder = db.OpenRecordset(strSQLHolder)

rstHolder.MoveFirst

Do While Not rstHolder.EOF

    'Select all transactions that have not previously been invoiced and sum the TxAmount fields
    strSQL = "SELECT * " _
    & "FROM (tblTransaction " _
    & "INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblTransaction.fkProductID = tblProduct.ProductID) " _
    & "INNER JOIN tblHolder ON tblProduct.fkHolderID = tblHolder.HolderID " _
    & "WHERE (((tblTransaction.TxInvoice) IS NULL) " _
    & "AND ((tblTransaction.TxType) = 'Fee') " _
    & "AND ((tblHolder.HolderID) = '" & rstHolder!HolderID & "'))"

    Set rstTrans = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    rstTrans.MoveFirst

    strSQLSum = "SELECT SUM(tblTransaction.TxAmount) As InvoiceSum " _
        & "FROM (tblTransaction " _
        & "INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblTransaction.fkProductID = tblProduct.ProductID) " _
        & "INNER JOIN tblHolder ON tblProduct.fkHolderID = tblHolder.HolderID " _
        & "WHERE (((tblTransaction.TxInvoice) IS NULL) " _
        & "AND ((tblTransaction.TxType) = 'Fee') " _
        & "AND ((tblHolder.HolderID) = '" & rstHolder!HolderID & "'))"

    Set rstSum = db.OpenRecordset(strSQLSum)

    If rstSum("InvoiceSum") > 0 Then
        'Add a new record to the invoice table with the sum of the amount and tax fields of all transactions not previously invoiced
        Set rstInvoice = db.OpenRecordset("tblInvoice")
        rstInvoice.AddNew
        rstInvoice("fkHolderID").Value = rstHolder("HolderID")
        rstInvoice("InvoiceDate").Value = Format(Now, "m/dd/yyyy")
        rstInvoice("Amount").Value = rstSum("InvoiceSum")
        rstInvoice("Tax").Value = rstInvoice("Amount") * 0.05
        rstInvoice.Update

        rstTrans.MoveFirst

        Do While Not rstTrans.EOF

            'Add newly created invoice number to transactions used to create invoice
            rstTrans.Edit
            rstTrans("TxInvoice").Value = rstInvoice("InvoiceID")
            rstTrans.Update

            rstTrans.MoveNext

        Loop

        rstTrans.Close
        rstInvoice.Close

    Else
        rstHolder.MoveNext
    End If
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        rstHolder.MoveNext
Loop

rstHolder.Close
db.Close
```

End Sub

It is working to some extent, but not entirely. When I click the button, it creates the invoice for the first holder (although only after I close the form that the button is on and then reopen it) then fails on the rstTrans("TxInvoice").Value = rstInvoice("InvoiceID") line saying there is no current record selected. If, after reopening the form, I click on the button again, it creates all of the invoices properly, but adds the invoice id from the invoice created after clicking the button the first time to all transactions in the Transaction table. I have a feeling I'm close, but don't know what is causing the failure. Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: One question I have is your line 'rstTrans("TxInvoice").Value = rstInvoice("InvoiceID")' ... I did not see anyplace where you touch field 'TxtInvoice' - is that an AutoNumber field?

Comment: TxInvoice is a field in the Transaction table, it is the same type as the InvoiceID from the Invoice table and is only used to indicate which invoice a transaction was applied to.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say where is field 'rstInvoice("InvoiceID")' ever populated? You add a new record to that table, but don't reference the field. Is it an AutoNumber?

Comment: Yes, that's right, it is the primary key of the Invoice table and its an autonumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly added record in tblInvoice is not guaranteed to be the current record after the AddNew. I suggest trying the following to save the key value for later use:

Old Code:

```
    rstInvoice.AddNew
    rstInvoice("fkHolderID").Value = rstHolder("HolderID")
    ...

        rstTrans.Edit
        rstTrans("TxInvoice").Value = rstInvoice("InvoiceID")
    ...
```

New code:

```
 Dim lInvoiceID As Long
    rstInvoice.AddNew 
    lInvoiceID = rstInvoice("InvoiceID")    ' Save the new key
    rstInvoice("fkHolderID").Value = rstHolder("HolderID")
    ...

        rstTrans.Edit
        rstTrans("TxInvoice").Value = lInvoiceID
```